# Jetpack Compose leadingIcon not visible

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am currently working with the jetpack compose text field. I tried adding a leading icon on the text field like below

```
leadingIcon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Search) },
```

but the IDE highlighted that `None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.` since the class`Icon()`. So I tried another option, shown below

```
 leadingIcon = { (Icons.Filled.Search) },
```

There was no exception thrown so I assumed that it would work, but now the leading Icon is not visible.
What could I be doing wrong?.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your first approach is correct, but since **1.0.0-alpha11** `contentDescription` is a required parameter. Basically the framework is forcing you to think about **accessibility**.

You should try with:

```
leadingIcon = { Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Search, contentDescription = null) }
```

See this tweet from Leland for more information about the decision:
https://twitter.com/intelligibabble/status/1355209643614584833?s=20

Comment: Thanks @Robert Nagy. I was using a sample  example from `1.0.0-alpha09`  forgetting to pass the arguments

Comment: Yes, I know the struggle, the api changed a lot in it's alpha versions and it's hard to follow the examples. Make sure you're checking out official documentations and the kotlinlang slack channel is also a great source of information

Answer (score 4):

The [`Icon`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#Icon(androidx.compose.ui.graphics.vector.ImageVector,kotlin.String,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color)) composable requires also the `contentDescription` property.
You have to use

```
leadingIcon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Search, "contentDescription") },
```